# Changing Component Background color dynamically with wait()

Tags: java, swing, colors, background, jpanel

I'm trying to do a funny `JFrame` so when mouse leaves the window, it changes the Panel `Background` color to some random colors (To gain user attention):

```
    wnd.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter(){
         @Override
        public synchronized void mouseExited(MouseEvent e){
            cond = true;
            while(cond){
                try{
                    wnd.getContentPane().setBackground(Color.getHSBColor((cont+=0.05), 1, 1));
                    wnd.setTitle("Num: "+cont);
                    wnd.getContentPane().repaint(); //With or without it doesn't work either
                    wait(100);
                    }
                    catch(InterruptedException ex){ Thread.currentThread().interrupt(); }
                }
            }
    });
```

The problem is that `Background` color doesn't change... It shows me the values of cont in the window title but color doesn't change. If I remove the cycle and just move the mouse inside and outside the panel, it changes... But I want to make it that when mouse leaves the window, it keeps changing the colors automatically until mouse gets back to it. Some kind of epilepsy (?)

I don't know why if I cycle it and make a delay with `wait()` it doesn't work.

Comment: You're blocking the Event Dispatching Thread, preventing from been unable to update the UI.

Comment: Have you read the documentation for `wait()`?  It's probably not what you want to use at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Swing is a single threaded framework, this means that anything to blocks the Event Dispatching Thread, will prevent it from processing the Event Queue (including repaint requests) and cause the application to appear as it has hung, cause it has.

You should never perform long running or blocking operations from within the context of the EDT.

Instead, in this case, you should use a Swing `Timer` to schedule a regular callback.  The benefit of this is that the callback is executed from within the context of the EDT, making it safe to use to update the UI (as Swing is also not thread safe).

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.Timer;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Test();
    }

    public Test() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.add(new TestPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class TestPane extends JPanel {

        private Timer updateTimer;

        public TestPane() {
            updateTimer = new Timer(100, new ActionListener() {
                private float cont = 0;

                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    setBackground(Color.getHSBColor((cont += 0.05), 1, 1));
                }
            });

            addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {

                @Override
                public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
                    updateTimer.start();
                }

                @Override
                public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
                    updateTimer.stop();
                }

            });
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(200, 200);
        }

    }

}
```

Take a look at [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/) and [How to use Swing Timers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html) for more details

Comment: Thanks! Yeah... I switched from .NET to java... I think I can't give the same use to `async void` and `await Task.Delay(int)` as C# does... But thanks! I just tested this with a timer and working :) Thanks you very much :P